# Java emulation of MySQL COMRESS DECOMPRESS functions

Tags: java, mysql, compression, percona

I'd like to insert some byte data into a mysql VARBINARY column. The data is large so I want to store it in a compressed way.

I'm using Percona 5.6 Mysql. I would like to  emulate the COMPRESS function of mysql in Java and then insert the result in the database. 
I would like to use MySql DECOMPRESS function in order to access this data. 
Is there a way to do it?

I have tried using standard java.zip package. but it doesn't work.

**Edit**. Phrased differently, what is the Java equivalent of PHP's `gzcompress` (ZLIB)?

Comment: What you mean _it doesn't work_?

Comment: Add something to help discover the answer.

Comment: Why? Let the database do it. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 3):

The result of COMPRESS is a four-byte little endian length of the uncompressed data, followed by a zlib stream containing the compressed data.

You can use the `Deflater` class in Java to compress to a zlib stream. Precede the result of that with the four-byte length.

Comment: Thanks Mark. My missing piece was the four-byte length of the uncompressed data is stored in little endian format. It worked beautifully!

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Implemented MYSQL Compress and DECOMPRESS

```
//Compress byte stream using ZLib compression
  public static byte[] compressZLib(byte[] data)  {
    Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
    deflater.setInput(data);
    deflater.finish();

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!deflater.finished()) {
      int count = deflater.deflate(buffer); // returns the generated code... index
      outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    try {
      outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
  }

//MYSQL COMPRESS.
  public static byte[] compressMySQL(byte[] data)  {
    byte[] lengthBeforeCompression = ByteBuffer.allocate(Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(data.length).array();
    ByteArrayOutputStream resultStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
      resultStream.write( lengthBeforeCompression );
      resultStream.write( compressZLib(data));
      resultStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return resultStream.toByteArray( );
  }

//Decompress using ZLib
  public static byte[] decompressZLib(byte[] data) {
    Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
    inflater.setInput(data);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try {
      while (!inflater.finished()) {
        int count = inflater.inflate(buffer);
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
      }
      outputStream.close();
    }catch (IOException ioe) {
    } catch (DataFormatException e) {
    }
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
  }

  //MYSQL DECOMPRESS
  public static byte[] decompressSQLCompression(byte[] input) {
    //ignore first four bytes which denote length of uncompressed data. use rest of the array for decompression
    byte[] data= Arrays.copyOfRange(input,4,input.length);
    return decompressZLib(data);
  }
```